# Docker Desktop (parse :2375: missing protocol scheme)

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I'm using Docker on Windows 10. Docker now requires me to include `-H localhost:2375` on all commands. Not sure what's changed but before I'm pretty sure I was able to issue docker commands without this.

Comment: It shall use named pipes by default. Try to "reset" inside Docker 10

Comment: I reset docker to factory default but still get the same error

Comment: @GregorySuvalian I've removed every reference I can find on my machine to docker, uninstalled docker and completely reinstalled it. Still getting the same problem

Comment: Check your environment variables `dir env:do*`

Comment: Somehow I ended up with an environment variable containing `:2375`! Deleting that has worked. If you create an answer @GregorySuvalian I'll tick it for you. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your environment variables making sure nothing modifies default docker behavior

`dir env:do*`